How to make Text numberOfLines not break the word
Whenever I use the numberOfLines property with truncation involved, the ellipsis often breaks the word.
So given the following:
<Text numberOfLines="{2}">
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam dolore cumque
  dignissimos necessitatibus ad sunt dolores. Beatae ex iusto nostrum magni,
  aperiam sed nemo, qui, aliquam error maiores debitis! Porro.
</Text>

It can end up looking like:
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam
  dolore cumque dignissimos necessitatibus ad sunt dolores. Be...

Is it possible to not break the word, and have the ellipsis at the end of a full word only? I can't find any native way or 3rd party package that does this.

Look at this, seems like a few options https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2496

I believe this behavior is by design. A word will only be truncated on the last line to fit as many words as possible across the width of your device viewport. If a word doesn't fit on any line other than the last line, it wraps around to the next line. Only the last line should break the word off if the full word does not fit.
